# How to start thread when at least one is finished

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 4 threads. Each prints the given letter x times every x second.
The task is to start 3 threads at once and the 4th one when at least one of the previous threads is finished.
I don't know how to notify this last thread to run in due time.

Comment: Can you clarify: is the 4th thread different from the first 3? As in, do you care which thread should be the 4th to run, or is it just that you want any one of the 4 to wait until one of the first 3 has finished?

Answer (score 3):

[CompletableFutures](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) are the modern way to accomplish this in an expressive way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    
    CompletableFuture<Void> a = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> print("A"), executor);
    CompletableFuture<Void> b = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> print("B"), executor);
    CompletableFuture<Void> c = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> print("C"), executor);
    CompletableFuture.anyOf(a, b, c).thenRunAsync(() -> print("D"), executor);
}

private static void print(String taskName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; ++i) {
        System.out.println("Task " + taskName + ": " + i);
    }
}
```

Run A, B and C, then when any one of them is done, run D.

You can simplify it even further by removing the executor and just using the fork/join pool, but it doesn't work so well in a self-contained example because they're daemon threads; the program will just end very quickly before it does much of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what is your assignment? Do you care about the work? The threads?

You can always "hack it" by making thread pool with three threads and give it four tasks:

```java
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    es.execute(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("A");
            try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    });
    es.execute(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("B");
            try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    });
    es.execute(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("C");
            try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    });
    es.execute(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("D");
            try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    });
```

Or alternatively make the threads yourself (D thread first), and at the end of the work of each (ABC) ask if D is running, if not, start it.

There is so many solutions to this with wildly different complexity, and whether they are alright depends solely on your context.

Answer (score 0):

To use semaphores to wait until one of 3 threads finishes, before starting a 4th different thread, you can initialise the semaphore to `0`. Before running  the 4th thread, you acquire the semaphore, but cannot, since it is `0`. When one of the 3 threads finishes, it releases the semaphore, allowing the 4th thread to run.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);
        char[] letters = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
        List<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int threadNum = 0; threadNum < 3; threadNum++) {
            int finalThreadNum = threadNum;
            Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.print(letters[finalThreadNum]);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                sem.release();
            });

            threadList.add(t);
            t.start();

        }


        Thread lastThread = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.print('d');
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        sem.acquire();
        lastThread.start();

        for (Thread t : threadList) {
            t.join();
        }
        lastThread.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `Semaphore`. The first 3 threads will take all the permits and when the first one releases a permit, the 4th will pick it up and run.

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(3, true);
    
    
    Runnable a = new Runnable() {   
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                    System.out.println("A");
                }                   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                semaphore.release();
            }
        }
    };
    Runnable b = new Runnable() {   
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                    System.out.println("B");
                }                   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                semaphore.release();
            }
        }
    };
    Runnable c = new Runnable() {   
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                    System.out.println("C");
                }                   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                semaphore.release();
            }
        }
    };
    
    Runnable d = new Runnable() {   
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
                System.out.println("D");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                semaphore.release();
            }
        }
    };
    
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    exec.execute(a);
    exec.execute(b);
    exec.execute(c);
    exec.execute(d);
}
```

Comment: What if the 4th thread's `semaphore.acquire()` happens before the other 3 threads' acquires (maybe this is unlikely, but possible)? Surely it's better to initialise the semaphore with 0 permits, and remove the `semaphore.acquire()` in the first 3 threads, leaving the `release`?

Comment: Shouldn't happen so long as the other threads are started first.  Worst case scenario, you could put a manual boolean synchronized lock in the 4th thread so it short circuits if it has already run.

Comment: You are at the mercy of the scheduler with this one. The scheduler might decide any one of A, B or C should pause immediately after starting, but before acquiring the semaphor. In such case, D might get the lock before those have started, let alone finished.

Comment: @Michael  I'm not sure how else to do it without some kludge to manually lock the 4th thread to a single execution.

Comment: @Ryan Give up on semaphores. See my answer :)

Comment: Your solution doesn't solve the problem, you just complicated my solution.  What could be done is to ditch the `Semaphore` for a `CountDownLatch` with a count of 1 with the 4th thread locked behind the latch.

Answer (score -1):

> What if the 4th thread's semaphore.acquire() happens before the other 3 threads' acquires...

You could use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for that. Building on @Ryan 's answer:

```java
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(3, true);
        CountDownLatch okToStartTaskD = new CountDownLatch(3);
        
        Runnable a = new Runnable() {   
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    semaphore.acquire();
                    okToStartTaskD.countDown();
                    ...
                }
                ...
            }
        };
        Runnable b = new Runnable() {   
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    semaphore.acquire();
                    okToStartTaskD.countDown();
                    ...                 
                }
            ...
            }
        };
        ...
        
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        exec.execute(a);
        exec.execute(b);
        exec.execute(c);
        try {
            okToStartTaskD.await();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            ...should never get here, but what if?...
        }
        exec.execute(d);
    }
```

Comment: Apart from being overly complicated, this doesn't fix the problem with @Ryan's answer. Your solution successfully prevents the `d` thread from being the first to acquire the semaphore, but you could still end up with the semaphore being acquired by `a`, `b` and `d`, then `c` being stuck waiting for until a thread finishes before being able to run.

Comment: @SolomonSlow "*When have you ever seen anything like that in any real program?*" It's not really that uncommon. It's basically the equivalent of JavaScript's [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) which wouldn't exist if there was no use-case for it. Suppose you have 2 or more sources for some data. You ask them all and you take the one that returns first. The only difference in this case is that A, B and C are just arbitrary tasks that don't return anything.

Comment: OK, That's fair. I guess I am not thinking clearly today. Deleting my previous comment. But @Oli still was right, my previous answer still was wrong, and I still have changed it to use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), only now I no longer have any opinion about the complexity of the code.